# Django authenticated user not active across the views

Tags: django

I am using ldap authentication for my Django project. I want all my views to have login required. When I logged in, it is taking me to the home page which was defined in my settings.py file as below
`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'`
But when I click on different view, which is present in other app in same project, I am losing the authentication. I am checking whether my user is active or not with the below code

`{% if user.is_active %} user is active with {{user}} {% else %} user is NOT active with {{user}} {% endif %}`

When I try to juggle between 2,3 views I am losing the authentication as it is showing *user is NOT active with AnonymousUser*.
How do I make my authentication intact across the views in my Django project?
I thought this is the problem with LDAP integration, but created a super user and tried with that user as well but again showing the same behavior. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Adding my urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from users.forms import LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('myapp.urls')),
    url('unittesting/', include('unittesting.urls', namespace="unittesting")),
    url("^login/", auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html', authentication_form=LoginForm), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), {'next_page': '/login'})
]
```

Comment: You need to show how you are actually logging the user in.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that you have to use `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}`

Comment: But the problem is that, my authentication is not active across the views. When i try to click on another view, i am losing the authentication

Answer (score 0):

Just Use only  `{% if user.is_authenticated %} {{ user }} {% endif %}`